# LoadProperty in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I upgraded my entity framework 4.3 database first project to the new entity framework 5.
<strike>Apparently I'm now using DbContext instead of ObjectContext.</strike>

I've replaced my old .edmx file with a new one. My old business code, that was previously using my 4.3 .edmx file, now has a problem with code using the `LoadProperty` method:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    Models.User user = context.Users.First(x => x.GUID == guid);
    context.LoadProperty(user, o => o.Settings);
    return user;
}
```

It seems that LoadProperty is not an available method in DbContext.

How can I can get strong typed loading anyway?

I suppose I could use

```
context.Users.Include("Settings")
```

but that is not strong typed and prone to typos.

Comment: You were not using EF4.3 if you used ObjectContext - EF4.3 was basically all about DbContext... If lazy loading is enabled you can just use .Settings property without having to explicitly load it. Note that it may trigger a trip to a database so if you are doing this frequently it may be cheaper to use .Include() as pointed below.

Comment: @Pawel: Oh sorry. I read a question about another problem I encountered after the update and quoted it with "apprently" to better describe my situation. I striked that sentence through.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Include method with Lambda too.
don't forget the using statement, because this Include comes from the DbExtension class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

...

```
context.Users.Include(u => u.Settings);
```

here is some info about the Include extension method: [msdn info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! I hope your answer will help others with the same problem

Comment: Epic Extension I must say. It's great since it's strongly typed.